# to get Time in minutes

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get time in minutes.
I have shared the details in below format.
I want the running time in Minute.
kindly help me.

```
start_time               end_time                running time(end_time-start_time)
7/7/2017 2:52:05 PM      7/7/2017 2:52:54 PM     I want it in Minute
```

Comment: Minutes relative to _what_ ?

Comment: Tag DBMS please

Comment: Column data types?

Comment: Both data type is in Date.

Comment: I want that time difference in minutes.

Answer (score 2):

If this is Oracle (plsql tag says maybe):

```
(end_time - start_time) * 24 /* days to hours */ * 60 /* hours to minutes */ as running_time
```